# Dynamically Select Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have 2 variables like so

```
var variable_1 = "foo";
var variable_2 = "bar";
```

I use a function to grab the value of a checkbox input and for each checkbox which is checked, I want to load the particular variable which depends on value of checkbox.

```
$("input:checked").each(function() {
    $(div).append('variable_'+$(this).val());
}
```

So I'd concatenate the text 'variable_' with the value of each checkbox.

Thanks!

Comment: If the variables are global, use `window['variable_' + $(this).val()]`

Comment: You'd better use object to store values `var values = {variable_1='foo', ...}` and access its properties by name `$(div).append(values['variable_' + $(this).val()])`

Comment: You can use `eval` to get value of any variable dynamically. like `$(div).append(eval("variable_" + $(this).val()))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because calling a variable or function from a user input is dangerous, and particularly if you are only using two different variables, you would be better off using a simple if statement.

This one is a ternary if:

```
var variable_1 = "foo";
var variable_2 = "bar";

$("input:checked").each(function() {
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    var append = (isChecked) ? variable_1 : variable_2;
    $(div).append(append);
}
```

Alternatively you could use a switch statement for multiple values.

Comment: Right, it could be bad to rely on the input value to show the next menu. Might it be better to have a server-side event push the data back to the client? This would prevent some wise guy changing the values from affecting the next menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval` to get any variable values dynamically.

```
var variable_1 = "foo";
var variable_2 = "bar";
```

`$("input:checked").each(function() {
    $(div).append(eval('variable_'+$(this).val()));
}`

Note: it's not the best solution because `eval` has some security issues as well.

Comment: eval is a very dangerous bit of code tho.

Comment: Yes, you are right `eval` has some security issues. But if he don't want to use object to save variable values or `window` to get variable value dynamically then I think eval is the last option he can do to get value dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Create object with properties and access that properties via `obj['prop']` notation, see code below:

```
var myObj = {'variable_1': 'foo', 'variable_2': 'bar'};
 $("input:checked").each(function() {
    var dynamicVariableName = 'variable_' + $(this).val()
    var dynamicVarValue = myObj[dynamicVariableName];
    $(div).append(dynamicVar);
}
```

If your variables lives under window it's better to create new global object which contains that variable rather than keeping that variables as globals.

Comment: putting variables on the window object is not best practice.

Comment: @TimOgilvy Well, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: So by concatenating a string you avoid it calling any meaningful method or property. Makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 0):

If the variables are **globals** then you can use

```
var y = window["variable_" + x];
```

to read or

```
window["variable_" + x] = y;
```

to write to them dynamically.

Better practice however is to use **an object** to store them instead of using separate variables...

```
var data = { variable_1: null,
             variable_2: null };

...

y = data["variable_" + x];
```

Javascript can also use `eval` to access dynamically variables, amazingly enough even local variables

```
function foo(s) {
    var x = 12;
    return eval(s);
}

console.log(foo("x"));
```

and even more amazingly this allows the dynamic creation of new local variables...

```
var y = 42;

function foo(s) {
    var x = 1;
    eval(s);
    return y; // may be global y or a local y defined by code in s
}

foo("x")          // returns 42
foo("var y = 99") // returns 99 (but global y is not changed!)
```

but these uses of `eval` should be considered more a bug than a feature and are best avoided (they also makes the code basically impossible to optimize or understand so "just don't do it"™).